# Unexpected output of inherited member function

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Consider the following code:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

class test{
    private:
        std::list<double> lst;

    public:
        int get_size(){
            return lst.size();
        }
};

class derived : public test{
    private:
        std::list<double> lst;

    public:
        derived(int u=8){
            for (int k =0 ; k < u; ++k){
                int n = lst.size();
                lst.push_back(0);
            }
        }
};

int main(){

    derived obj = derived();

    std::cout << obj.get_size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to understand why the output of the above code isn't `8`. I thought that the idea of inheritance allows one to use member functions of the base class in the derived class, but it seems that this isn't really working here. Of course I could make the `get_size` function `virtual` in the base class and then copy paste the code into the derived class and add `override`, but this seems really weird, since in this case I could just re-implement the function anyways... So can somebody explain how we need to modify the code from above to get the output `8`?

Comment: You can't overload or use polymoprhism for member variables. The `get_size` function only knows about the `test` class and therefore uses `test::lst`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so you actually have to copy the function into the derived class? There is no other way around this?

Comment: You could make `test::lst` *`protected`* and remove the `derived::lst` member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the `list` from `test`. You're declaring a new `list` and using that instead in your constructor for `derived`.

On the other hand, `size()` is using the `list` from `test`.

If you want to add to the `test` `list` from inside `derived`, you should make `test`'s list `protected`, not private. And you should remove the `list` with a duplicate name from `derived`.

Answer (score 1):

The `lst` in your `derived` class is not the same one as used in your base class.

You should make `lst` `protected` instead of `private` in your `test` base class.
Then you can use the same variable in the derived class. Of course you also need to delete the `lst` declaration in your derived class.